# type="application/xop+xml" but expected 'text/xml;

Tags: java, web-services

We develop a java web service and im able to consume it fine by soupui, but when we try to consume it using other client it give us

```
type="application/xop+xml" but expected 'text/xml error
```

Im looking where I can change the message encoding return to be the expected, but i do not find any way.

Thanks,